# sqlalchemy, log values after and before

Tags: python, orm, model, sqlalchemy

I need to check which fields in my model has been changed before update it. to make a log, and compare the values after and before.

How can I do ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, look what I found.

[sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.History](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session.html#sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.History)

I can use this in the before_update event, to make a log with the changes.

Thanks very much.